# Android error “unable to find explicit activity class” c#

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin, splash-screen

My activity is called CwiLogInActivity. I declare it in my Splash screen like so:

```
StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(CwiLogInActivity)));
```

**error message:**

```
Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {CwiMyCardApp.CwiMyCardApp/md5de4cbc02688eb358b61123b78d100d94.CwiLogInActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

**Android manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="CwiMyCardApp.CwiMyCardApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:label="CwiMyCardApp">
    <activity android:name=".CwiLogInActivity"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I am using cheeseknife to resolve my resources and I have no issues with compiling. I am getting my error at runtime.

**CwiLogInActivity.cs**

```
class CwiLogInActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(CwiLogInActivity).Name;

        [InjectView(Resource.Id.loginName)]
        EditText loginName;
        [InjectView(Resource.Id.passWord)]
        EditText passWord;
        [InjectView(Resource.Id.loginButton)]
        Button loginButton;

        [InjectOnClick(Resource.Id.loginButton)]
        void OnClickMyButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This code will run when the button is clicked ...

        }

        [InjectOnFocusChange(Resource.Id.loginName)]
        void OnLoginFocusChange(View v, bool hasFocus)
        {
            if (hasFocus)
            {
                loginName.Text = "";
                loginName.SetTextColor(Color.Argb(150, 000, 000, 000));
            }
        }

        [InjectOnFocusChange(Resource.Id.loginName)]
        void OnPasswordFocusChange(View v, bool hasFocus)
        {
            if (hasFocus)
            {
                passWord.Text = "";
                loginName.SetTextColor(Color.Argb(150, 000, 000, 000));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
            // Inflate the activity layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginLayout);

            // Use Cheeseknife to inject all attributed view
            // fields and events. For an activity injection,
            // simply pass in the reference to this activity.
            Cheeseknife.Inject(this);
        }
    }
```

This seems to be in line with most of the solutions offered to other people who had my problem. Yet mine still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `[Activity]` attribute defined on this activity. Thus it never gets injected in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: hmm now it compiles but just goes to a blank screen...i added `[Activity(label="MyCwiCardApp")]` where "MyCwiCardApp" is the name of the application

Comment: Sounds like a different issue than the one described here. Maybe your injected view items are not working appropriately? Try to give the `SetContentView()` a layout that you know will display just to double check.

Comment: I have a breakpoint set at SetContentView() and it never triggers